# python or statement, try, if, or getattr

Tags: python, python-3.x

I read a lot of articles about what it's better to check attribute and set default.

But all the people compare 'try', 'if' and 'getattr', but none use 'or'.

In [this](https://calidae.blog/to-get-or-not-getattr-with-or-without-attr-17ffa03939d2) article, I found reason about performance, reflection, and typing. This is why I choose this article.

But it doesn't analize or compare with 'or', and I don't know why I don't see information about it. It is less pythonic? lost in performance? is less reliable?

example from the link

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar=None):
        self.bar = bar
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, baz):
        self.baz = baz
foo_with_bar = Foo(Bar(42))
foo_without_bar = Foo()
```

## and to test the different options

```
def test_if(foo):
    baz = 'value_I_want'
    if foo.bar:
        baz = foo.bar.baz
    return baz

def test_ternary(foo):
    return foo.bar.baz if foo.bar else 'value_I_want'

def test_exception(foo):
    try:
        baz = foo.bar.baz
    except AttributeError:
        baz = 'value_I_want'
    return baz

def test_getattr(foor):
    return getattr(foo.bar, 'baz', 'value_I_want')
```

And here I whould like add one more option:

```
def test_or_statement(foo):
   retur foo.bar or 'value_I_want'
```

This 'or' statement is the one I can't see compared with the other, when it's better to use it, or avoid.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `or`?

Comment: Could you add an example (or multiple)? Its unclear what you're talking about

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about syntax like we see in javascript sometimes like `an_object.a_falsy_value || a_default`

```js
const obj = {a:0}
console.log(obj.a || 2); // 2
console.log(obj.b || 2); // 2
```

this can't work always the same way in python:

```py
class Obj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

o = Obj()
print(o.a or 2) # 2
print(o.b or 2) # AttributeError: 'Obj' object has no attribute 'b'
print(getattr(o, 'b', 2)) # 2
```

Conclusion:

Using the `or` operator to provide a default value will work only for falsy values which are not undefined.

If you try to get an attribute or a dict key that doesn't exist you'll get `AttributeError` or `KeyError`.

So the safest way to provide default value for an attribute that could be not present at all is to use accordingly `getattr(obj, attrname, default)`, or `dict.get(key, default)`, etc.

Comment: but in this case you can't compare it in the use of a dictionary because getattr doesn't work in a dictionary even if you can 'force' it, right?, I refer to class attributes

Comment: @bla37381111 Yes you're right the dict example was not relevant, I removed it, even so problem would be the same with a dict, you'll get a KeyError trying to get an undefined key.